# DirectX11 How to strip unused variables from constant buffer?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am calling `D3DReflect()` to deduce the layout of the constant buffers used by a compiled shader, and I noticed that they often contain unused variables.

I am already using `D3DStripShader()` to strip debug info, and I was wondering if there is a similar way to strip those unused variables from constant buffers before calling `D3DReflect()` ?

---

Is it usually a good practice ?
 
Since it would imply most of the time to have one cbuffer per original cbuffer/stage/program, I don't know if the gain of stripping unused variables would be superior to the loss of having more (smaller) cbuffers ?

Comment: Sure they are unused?   Most GPUs will very happily optimize out any truly unused vars...  In any case I would leave them be, as there are almost certainly byte-alignments and twiddly little optimizations going on if they were loaded with data even once...

Comment: They are unused because the compiled code don't read them (detected using `D3D_SVF_USED`), but they are still in the cbuffers and I would like to create a new coarse cbuffer without them (or pack the original).

Comment: How do you compile shaders?

Comment: I am using `D3DCompile()` with the flag `D3DCOMPILE_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL3`.

Comment: How is your constant buffer declared? There is a possibility that you may be seeing padding, or that a variable is not referenced by the currently compiled shader but is referenced by a different shader in the same file. I would also be very wary of removing unused variables in a constant buffer, as the compiled bytecode references vector offsets into that buffer. If one of the variables exists in the middle, you've just invalidated all of the code that references any variables after the one you deleted.

Comment: Yes this is often due to different stages of the same effect not using the same variables, and yes I am searching for a way not breaking the compiled code (ie specialized cbuffer per shader program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *simple* way to do this. The naive view of constant buffers was that everyone would make explicit structures to hold their constants, and those structures would be shared by both shaders and the calling C++ code (or C#, whatever). Thus, if the shader compiler altered the layout of the structure, everything would break.

This makes sense in the microscopic view when working on DX sample apps. For a larger project, many people don't do that. Instead, they have older style shaders with constants declared at global scope. On DX9 and other similar platforms, the constants were mapped to registers, so the compiler could strip unused constants (and it did). For DX11, the compiler takes all of those global constants, and puts them in a special "global" constant buffer. Then it decides that you really care about the structure of that buffer, so it refuses to remove anything.

So, there are generally two options:

1. Break your constants into multiple constant buffers, grouped roughly into sets that are used together. The compiler WILL strip an entire constant buffer that's unused, so you can use that to get coarse stripping. This is time consuming, and you have to maintain your set partition, but it might be good enough, depending on your situation.
2. Implement constant stripping yourself. This is what we do... After compiling all of the shaders once, we use the reflection API to get a list of all the constants in the binary. That information includes the flag that indicates if the constant is used or not. For each used constant, we simply declare it again, as normal. For each constant that wasn't used, we emit a similar declaration, but mark the variable as static. That has the effect of removing it from any constant buffer (because it's treated as a compile-time constant by the shader compiler). Then we re-compile the shaders, and the newly generated global constant buffer only contains the used constants.

This is also a bunch of work (and in our implementation, we have to wrap all constant declarations in a macro - the wrapper code builds a big string with all of the static/non-static declarations, and defines `STRIPPED_CONSTANT_DEFINITIONS` to contain that string):

```
#if defined (STRIPPED_CONSTANT_DEFINITIONS)
STRIPPED_CONSTANT_DEFINITIONS
#else
bool someConstant;
float4 color;
...
#endif
```

Note that you *need* to still declare the stripped constants as static, because any unused code paths or uncalled functions that refer to those variables will cause the shader not to compile, otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was aiming for. Macro fallbacking to a static var is indeed a clever way to strip the global cbuffer. Are you using only one unique stripped constant buffer per program or do you try to share them between different stages ?

Comment: We still use the effects framework to load our shaders, but we compile each shader stage independently (and twice, using the above trick). So we have an included header with all of our constants for all stages, but VS/PS/etc... each get a unique global cbuffer that contains only the constants used in that stage. Because of the number of shaders, and the complexity that would result, we don't make any effort to share cbuffer layouts between different shaders or stages.